# How to remove dynamic url breadcrumb using Codeigniter breadcrumb helper

Tags: codeigniter, breadcrumbs

I am using codeigniter breadcrumb helper from https://bitbucket.org/cahva/codeigniter-autocrumb/src/59a0dbe8aba2/helpers/breadcrumb_helper.php to set a simple breadcrumb. One of my url as follows,

http://example.dev/jobs/c0001/j0002

and here `c001` stands for customer with `customer_id` one and `j0002` for job with `job_id` two and `0001` and `0002` are dynamic. Breadcrumb for this page shown as follows,

```
Home    › Jobs  ›  C0001 › J0002
```

but I need it as

```
Home    ›  Jobs
```

Is it possible to trim last two (dynamic) sections?

Comment: can you chekc this one may be it will help http://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-minimize-url-and-remove-index-php/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo set_breadcrumb('',array($this->uri->segment(2),$this->uri->segment(3))); ?>
```

Try it let me know if it works